# swift repeat func: expected identifier in function declaration

Tags: swift

I'm using a Swift learning book about extensions with a closure as a parameter.

In the book, it told me

```
extension Int {
    func repeat(work: () -> ()) {
        for _ in 0..<self {
            work()
        }
    }
}
```

---

On the line

```
func repeat(work: () -> ()) {
```

Xcode tells me

> Expected identifier in function declaration

---

and on the line:

```
for _ in 0..< self {
```

Xcode tells me

> Braced block of statements is an unused closure

and

> Expected ‘{’ to start the body of for-each loop

---

Can anyone can tell me why these errors occur and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the posted code:

1. `extensionInt` should be `extension Int`, although I suspect this is a typo in you post
2. As @Zhao Yi pointed out, `repeat` is a Swift keyword, you need to rename your function (e.g. repeatWork)
3. The Swift Half-Open Range Operator requires either an empty space on both sides, or no space on both sides. Both these are valid:

   ```
   0 ..< self
   0..<self
   ```

Finally, you can call this function like this:

```
2.repeatWork({
    print("Hello")
})
```

or this:

```
2.repeatWork {
    print("Hola")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`repeat` is a keyword you can't use as a function name. Rename it to something else:

```
extension Int {
    func repeat1(work: () -> ()) {
        for _ in 0..<self {
            work()
        }
    }
}
```